# wordpress function through ajax not being called

Tags: functions, ajax

I have written following js code

```
jQuery(".selectbox").change(function(){
 var id = this.id;
var key_id=id;
 var selectname='';

     jQuery.post(
    // see tip #1 for how we declare global javascript variables
    MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    {
        // here we declare the parameters to send along with the request
        // this means the following action hooks will be fired:
        // wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit and wp_ajax_myajax-submit
        action : 'get-mata-value',

        // other parameters can be added along with "action"
        prev_metakey : jQuery(this).val(),
        metakey: key_id
    },
    function( result ) {
       if(result['success'] != false)
        {
            jQuery.each(result,function(index,value){
                jQuery('#' +id).append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
            });
        }
    }
);
```

});

and function is:

```
wp_localize_script( 'script', 'MyAjax',
    array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    )
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vehicle_parts.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);


    add_action("wp_ajax_get-mata-value", "get_mata_value");
    add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get-mata-value", "get_mata_value");
    function get_mata_value()
    {   
        global $wpdb;
    $key=$_POST["metakey"];
        $prev_value=$_POST["prev_metakey"];
        $result=array();

     $result=$wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '$key'");

     return($result);

    }
```

when I change select box the function is not being called.

Comment: Are you enqueueing your script and localizing ajaxurl? Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: yes it has been enqueueing. only php function not being called

Comment: Can you share the enqueue code as well?

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vehicle_parts.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

Comment: There is a reference to MyAjax.ajaxurl - where is the being localized?

Comment: please provide solution, I don't have any other code to show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51883/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-welcher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I don't think the MyAjax variable is being localized using [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

In your case, you'll most likely need something like the following:

```
wp_localize_script( 'script', 'MyAjax',
    array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    )
);
```

That said, I don't really have enough information to provide a more detailed answer.

EDIT: This and the enqueue scripts call should be inside of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts, 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
function enqueue_my_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vehicle_parts.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

    wp_localize_script( 'script', 'MyAjax',
        array( 
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: still function not being called

Comment: Where are you adding this code? It should be in the same callback that enqueues the script. I really can't help much more without more details. Are you seeing any console or network errors in your console?

Comment: added code in question

Comment: You should be adding the enqueue and localization code inside a callback added to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action

Comment: I have still issue with function call

Answer (score 0):

as per code [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) you should *localize* after *enqueue*ing your javascript.

> IMPORTANT! wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script has been registered using wp_register_script() or wp_enqueue_script().

**Edit:** you need really to `echo` your output from your ajax callback and use `exit()` or `die()` after that.